# AVSpeechSynthesizer can't work with Japanese on the real device of iOS9

Tags: ios9

I can use AVSpeechSynthesizer API for text-to-speech to speak japanese on the simulator yet it's not working on the real devices producing log as below. Any advice?

> AXSpeechAssetDownloader|error| ASAssetQuery error fetching results
>   (for com.apple.MobileAsset.MacinTalkVoiceAssets) Error Domain=ASError
>   Code=21 "Unable to copy asset information"
>   UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}

Here is the source

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:speechStr];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"ja-JP"];
[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check the setting>accessibilty>speech>speech selection enabled or not, just enable it in ios 9 or greater.then,
Here is my working code, if it will help you then.

```
 NSMutableString *mutableString = [self.utteranceString mutableCopy];
  //  CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)mutableString, NULL, kCFStringTransformToLatin, NO);
    //CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)mutableString, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);

    AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    AVSpeechUtterance *synUtt = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:self.utteranceString];
    [synUtt setVoice:[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"ja-JP"];
    self.speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    self.speechSynthesizer.delegate = self;
     // set your class to conform to the AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate protocol
      float speechSpeed = 0.5f;
      [synUtt setRate:speechSpeed];
      UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;

    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
    [synUtt setVolume:1.0];
    [self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:synUtt];
```